# SqLite и phonegap: создать новую бд и внести в неё данные

Tags: phonegap, sqlite, javascript

Не могу найти нормальной  литературы по этому поводу. 
[На сайте указывается](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Database)  как работать с уже созданной БД.
Но вопрос, как создать ее и внести в нее данные?
Спасибо.

Comment: В OpenDatabase Вы указываете имя базы данных, если такой базы не существует- она будет создана.

Comment: Не будет ли приложение создавать его каждый раз? Или создается только при компиляции программы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В OpenDatabase Вы указываете имя базы данных, если такой базы не существует- она будет создана.
База данных создается только один раз, дальше она может только обновляться.
Для обновления баз данных создаются примерно такие функции:

```
db.changeVersion("", "1.0", function(bd){
        bd.executeSql('CREATE TABLE test (id, name)');
    }); // это при создании базы данных
db.changeVersion("1.0", "1.1", function(bd){
        bd.executeSql('CREATE TABLE test2 (id2, name2)');
    }); // это обновление версии 1.0 до 1.1
```

Если хотите больше узнать на эту тему читайте про WebSQL- PhoneGap просто предоставляет обертку для этой HTML5 технологии.

Comment: Вопрос. Можно ли хранить аудио-файлы в SqLite? 
Если нет, то где хранить различные типы файлов?